# $\int \sin\theta\, d\theta = \int\,d\cos\theta$ or $-\int\,d\cos\theta$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$\int \sin\theta\, d\theta = \int\,d\cos\theta, \tag{1}$ or $\int \sin\theta\, d\theta = -\int\,d\cos\theta \tag{2}$

which one is correct? Due to $\sin\theta\,d \theta = -d\cos\theta$, I think (2) is correct. However (2) is so easy to mislead if someone what to apply definite integrals. Take the wrong equation below as an example.

$\int^\pi_0 \sin\theta\, d\theta = -\int^1_{-1}\,d\cos\theta$.

And with interpreting indefinite integrals as the definite integrals in $[a, \theta]$, $\int \sin\theta\, d\theta \rightarrow \int^\theta_a \sin\theta\, d\theta$.

We don't need to add a minus sign to reverse the variable and the lower bound.

$\int^\theta_a \sin\theta\, d\theta = \int^{\cos\theta'}_{a'}\,d\cos\theta'$.

Does this imply that we can use (1)?

Comment: It should've been $-\int_{1}^{-1}d(\cos\theta)=\int_{-1}^1d(\cos\theta)=2$, because $\cos:0\to 1,\pi\to-1$ and not the other way round. In other words, (2) is correct, you just didn't do the substitution correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$ It is correct that $\d(\cos\theta)=-\sin\theta\,\d\theta$ simply because the derivative of $\cos\theta$ is $-\sin\theta$. In your example,
$$ \int_0^\pi\sin\theta\,\d{\theta} = -\int_{1}^{-1}\d(\cos\theta)=\int_{-1}^1\d(\cos\theta) $$
because, when $\theta=\pi$, $\cos\theta=-1$, and when $\theta=0$, $\cos\theta=1$. You need to be careful when doing substitutions because even when "integrating over" the same region, the direction is meaningful and important.